# gerund "persuading" and noun "persuasion"

Tags: grammar

> National governments and states will **need persuading that** cities should have more power, especially as many will also be begging for money. They should step back anyway. Great cities are obnoxious, but they are normally big contributors to national budgets. And the trick they perform for their countries is not just economic. Cities are where people learn to live in a modern, open society. They are machines for creating citizens.

---

I think gerund is only used for verbs without noun form. But here persuade has noun persuasion, so why is it "persuading" instead of "persuasion"? Will the sentence meaning change a lot if using "persuasion"?

Comment: In your particular example, the noun "persuasion" cannot satisfy the complement requirements of "need", which here are either a non-finite clause ("they will need persuading", or the passive "They wilI need to be persuaded")

Comment: Thank you. But I am still confused. The definition of "persuasion" is  "The action or process of persuading someone or of **being persuaded to do or believe something.**".   With the "being persuaded",  why is it not satisfied here?

Comment: Because "National governments and states will need being persuading that cities... " is unacceptable, probably ungrammatical.

Comment: Thank you.Now I got it. It's just verb pattern of "need".